# Члены предложения и способы их выражения

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения

Очень сильно мучает вопрос, а именно как соотнести член предложения к нужному слову? Со школьной программы обычно учат лишь, что подлежащее - это сущ., сказуемое - глаг., определение - прил., и т. п., но ведь любой член предложения может быть любой частью речи. И вот как определить, чем выражено сказуемое, подлежащее или прилагательное - ведь все они могут быть выражены одной частью речи, допустим инфинитивом, местоимением, наречием. Т. е. как угодно, так и формулируй. Ну, к примеру:

```
Курить вредно. - "курить" подлежащее
Жить – значит бороться. - "значит бороться" сказуемое
Их объединило желание увидеться. - "увидеться" определение
```

И все они являются глаголами.

И собственно интересует вопрос, как определить что чему принадлежит? По смыслу анализировать каждое слово (допустим "курить" - это главная речь текста)? Или задавать вопрос (что? курить, хоть и привык задавать глагольный вопрос "что делать")? Может какие-то морфологические признаки выдают? Или что-то другое?

Comment: *их объединило желание увидеться. - "увидеться" определение* - это по какой же грамматике?

Comment: Вот и меня немного в ступор вгоняет это, увидел подобное на этом сайте: http://www.orfo.ru/tutorial/html/def_sentmem.htm, - но это не единственный пример.

Comment: А точнее можете дать ссылочку?

Comment: Точнее ссылочку не получится, т.к информация структура страницы меняется на js и ссылка не формируется. Просто кликните на "определение", там будут "несогласованные", последний пример.

Comment: (+), а, понял. Они трактуют жто как "желание какое?",а не "желание чего". Ну в принципе это не абсурдно, надо просто спросить у учителей, как сейчас принято трактовать подобное. ну вот как раз тот случай, когда надо просто принять на веру и запомнить.

Comment: Примеры с Википедии передрали. А там тоже умники сидят - не всегда расхлебаешь. )))

Comment: Ссылки вроде отображаются, а вкладки не раскрываются)

Comment: Да, обычно на вики так выставят, что сломаешься, пока поймешь, но все же Вы все правильно трактуете и понятнее стало. То есть исходить можно только из вопросов и смысла слова? Никаких более признаков нет?

Comment: В рамках школьных представлений, насколько понимаю, нет. Ну еще прием: разбор делается строго начиная с главных членов, с остальными тогда много проще.  Ну все остальное, чем можно в принципе воспользоваться, это уже семантическая роль, т.е. те же вопросы к членам предложения, только поставленные на службу структурному языкознанию, а его в школе не проходят. Но, повторюсь, подождите преподавателей, уверен, ответят и поправят, если я что наврал.

Comment: Хм, интересно, я и забыл про семантику, попробую пока с этой стороны подойти к понимаю. Т.е задается вопрос к члену предложения и подгоняется семантическая роль к нему?(Если ,конечно, каждая семантическая роль совпадает с членом предложением, то будет замечательно). А литературы не посоветуете? а то что-то гугл скудно выдает об этом информацию :(

Comment: Нет. Вы, видимо не совсем понимаете термин семантическая роль. Вот поэтому я и не хотел скатываться на академические подходы. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C Но раз уж вам так надо искать приключений, то в русском языке подлежащее это логический агенс, а сказуемое - логический предикат.  Да и то, есть некоторые оговорки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильный вопрос - это главное. Но бывает, что и это проблематично, тогда вспоминаем, что грамматическая основа – это организующий центр, своеобразный каркас.Подлежащее - предмет речи(о чём или о ком говорится в предложении?). Сказуемое этот предмет речи утверждает, отрицает, характеризует по действию, признаку, времени, реальности и т.д.Общий вопрос: что говорится о предмете речи?Чаще - что предмет делает?Каков он? Что это такое?
подлежащее выражается:

•   Именем существительным: Скоро пойдет снег.

•   Любой частью речи в роли сущ. Именем прилагательным: Новое требует много знаний. Причастием: Говорящий часто ошибается. Числительным:Семеро одного не ждут. Местоимением: Всякий это знает. Союзом: Но-противительный союз. Междометием: По лесу разносилось громкое ау.К нам завтра входит светлым и лучистым.

•   Инфинитивом: Жить – Родине служить.

•   Словосочетанием: Мы с другом пошли на рыбалку.Все три всадника ехали молча.Что-то слышится родное.

Фразеологизмом: Филькина грамота - это поговорка.

Сказуемое выражается:

•   Глаголом: Стоит хорошая погода.

•   Существительным: Москва – столица России.

•   Прилагательным: Мне мил стихов российский жар.

•   Прилагательным в сравнительной степени: Каждые сутки разлуки для меня длиннее года.

•   Наречием: Все у нас хорошо.

•   Причастием: Наша семья причастна к науке.

•   Устойчивым словосочетанием (фразеологизмом): Здоровье мое - ни тпру, ни ну.

Сложности в определении второстепенных членов касаются прежде всего инфинитива, как, например, в Вашем случае.Инфинитив может быть любым членом предложения - и главным, и второстепенным. Он может  не только входить в сост.глагольное сказ-е (Я люблю петь), но и быть простым глагольным сказуемым: А Татьяна бежать! Вася, давай играть! Делать она ничего не делала.

Трудность составляет найти инфинитив-дополнение(объектный инфинитив).Инфинитивное дополнение называет действие не подлежащего-субъекта, а другого действующего лица. Я решил уехать-сост. глагольное сказ.НО: Они просили меня (о чём?)уехать.Просили-сказуемое,дополнение уехать, потому что просили они, а уезжать надо мне.

Инфинитив-определение помогает раскрыть содержание предмета, которое обозначено отвлечённым существительным Я отказался от мысли (какой?) уехать сегодня.Уехать-определение.

Инфинитив-обстоятельство бывает обычно при глаголах движения (пошёл, поехал, вёз, нёс)или при глаголах отказа от движения(задержался, остался): Мужик гнал гусей (зачем?)продавать.Продавать - обстоятельство цели.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как сказуемое может характеризовать по признаку подлежащее, если этим занимается определение? Это как-то нелогично, причем такое я видел в разных источниках, что от сказуемого можно задавать вопрос "какой?"
Или получается, что сказуемое замещает определение? Ведь определение, как второстепенный член уточняет, дополняет, но если уточнять нечего и единично указывается какой-то признак, то это сказуемое, - верно понимаю? 

Например: вечер (какой?) тихий, - тихий в данном случае сказуемое.

Comment: Не от сказуемого можно задавать вопрос "каков предмет?", а К сказуемому. Сказуемое - это то главное, что говорится о предмете речи, а это может быть и действие субъекта, и признак его, и количество, и что угодно. Просто чаще всего сказуемое называет действие предмета, потому обычно начинают его поиск с вопроса "что делает?". Если действия нет, задают вопрос "каков предмет?"- Голос был громкий .Или " что есть предмет?" - Это была наша родина. Это-подлежащее, была родина - сказуемое.

Answer (score 0):

А вопросы к членам предложения в школе теперь задавать не учат?
Понимаю, академический подход предполагает и несколько другой способ, но для школы-то?!

Подлежащее оветвечает на вопрос "кто?" или "что?" так что тут спутать трудно, разве что с дополнением в винительном падеже.

Сказуемое - на вопрос "Что делает [подлежащее]?" (делало, сделало, будет делать - и т.п.), "чем является?" (являлось). Так что тут тоже понятно.

Бываю спорные случаи, но это объективно, грамматика не всегда хагоняется в формальные рамки.

Не знаю, что добавить. Задавайте вопросы - и все у вас получится.

Comment: Сами вопросы задавать-то непроблемно. С винительным падежом проблем нет, если задавать вспомогательный вопрос. Но вот как-то сложно дается это понимание, что подлежащее выражается глаголом, или определение существительным... Получается, чтобы определить надо лишь задавать вопрос? Других никаких способов нет?

Comment: Подождите, кто-нибудь из преподавателей ответит. Я не хочу в методический процесс вмешиваться. Мне казалось, что вопросы - вещь безотказная. А вот объяснять это в терминах теоретической грамматике, на языке всяких агенсов-пациенсов и прочих актантов - это не всякий неподготовленный мозг выдержит.

Comment: Хорошо, подожду, и спасибо Вам за ответы.